# BEGIN TRANSACTION vs BeginTransaction()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Should I be using `BeginTransaction` over calling the SQL code directly as a command `"BEGIN TRANSACTION"`? When I've been searching for the answer to my next question all the examples used `BeginTransaction`. Is there any difference and advantage with one over the other?

Comment: We might need to see some actual code samples, especially for your last mentioned situation.

Comment: Actually when I write a test the second problem goes away. More investigation required on that one.

Comment: Have put it in another question now I've repeated it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492943/is-this-transaction-being-rollbacked-for-me

Comment: Why didn't you just edit this question?

Comment: Initially I thought it was my mistake so edited it out - then when I saw it again and got some demo code showing it I thought it seemed like a good question in its own right.